# Is storing a user id in JWT enough to verify the identity?

Tags: cookies, jwt

I have been thinking to try out JWT as an alternative to the old session based authentication for performance reasons (i.e. no additional SQL lookup for session id in database just to get the user id for each and every HTTP request) and usability reasons (JWT is gonna be used in HTTP headers instead of cookies so that my app can be used as RESTFUL API and accessed by non-browser clients like mobile apps, also adding JWT in HTTP headers eliminates the danger of CSRF). Since the payload is signed with a secure HMAC like SHA256, it's nearly impossible to forge the payload. Additionally, the user id itslef isn't really a secret and is used publicly by the app.

I am thinking of using a payload that is something like this:

```
{
  id: "1234abcd",
  iat: 1522779638
}
```

where `iat` is a unix timestamp at which the JWT was created and this can be used to expire the JWT message and also harden the security by randomizing the hash for the same id.

My question is, assuming that I am going to apply strict HTTPS connection for my app in production, is using this unencrypted payload secure enough to verify user's identity and initiate unsafe methods like POST methods (e.g. follow a user, unfollow a user, etc...) that's as secure as the session based authentication? Do I need to encrypt the payload using something like AES-192 or AES-256 just to be more sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems as being enough to authenticate the user and secure the token in transit. However, the problem could be that with this system, you would not have a good way to revoke such a token. So if the token is stolen, it can be used forever. You may want to have a way for user to revoke these tokens. There are many scenarios where token could be stolen, from malware through stolen phone to logging in on insecure PC let's say in an internet cafe.

One possibility would just be to add a single "not-before" column to the users table and refuse tokens with `iat` lower then that. So the user could revoke all previously issued tokens by setting this column to the current timestamp. This would require access to the database, but only to the users table using ID which you will probably want to do anyway.

Comment: Yes, `iat`entry is also going to be used for invalidation if it's older than 6 months or something. So it's not just here for randomizing the hash for same id. Excluding the possibility of stealing the JWT since also the session id can be stolen by various means, is this unencrypted payload enough to make an equally secure authentication as the session id method?

Comment: I mean, is encrypting the payload is some sort of useless in this case?

Comment: @plsno I am not sure what you mean. Encrypting the token in addition to HTTPS is useless. If HTTPS is broken, the token can be used whether encrypted or not. However, it can't really be used without HTTPS if that is what you are thinking.

Comment: I understand that the whole HTTP message is encrypted at the TLS level, I meant by encrypting the payload, that it can look like a random token to whoever decode the JWT, so that nobody can understand that I am just using the user id directly as means of authentication and not some random token that acts as a session id. I hope you can get what I mean since my English isn't that good so I apologize.

Comment: @plsno Well, ok. You could do that, but what is the importance of that? The attacker can know you are using id and it won't help him at all.

Comment: in that case I will use a symmetric key algorithm like AES-256 or AES-192 with the same key for all payloads, along side with a randomly generated IV for each payload, this will look as if it's a completely random token that doesn't leak any hint that it's just an encrypted json that includes the user id and not some random session id that's gonna be checked against a database for instance, is this making the payload more secure or I am just being paranoid since the user id itself isn't even secret and is used publicly anyway in the app?

Comment: @plsno I am now not sure what you want to do. Is the app going to encrypt the payload, or is the token just going to be encrypted? Because if the app is encrypting, than how do you exchange keys without the attacker being able to see them?

Comment: the app is gonna encrypt the payload of the JWT using AES, the key of AES is gonna stay inside the app itself and won't be seen by anybody else

Comment: the app here is a HTTP server, I don't need to exchange any key with anybody since the goal is that only the server is able to decrypt the JWT payload

Comment: @plsno Ok, so if I understand correctly, the server will create (sign) the JWT, then encrypt it and send it to the client. The client will not be able to decrypt it. It will send the encrypted JWT as is back to the server with each request. Well, you can do that if you want, but it will really not help much. Shouldn't hurt either dough.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, my goal here is to make the payload looks completely random and anybody who can decode JWT doesn't conclude that I am just using the user id itself as method of authentication, this can make my payload unrecognizable from other methods like random token payloads that are used as session ids that are looked up against a SQL or Redis cache to get the user id.

Comment: @plsno You can go for it. IMO won't help with security much, because when the attacker sees the encrypted token, he does not care what it is or how it works, he can just use it. But as I said, it shouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, if you don't mind since I cannot upvote, I will not mark the answer as accepted for now to see if there are more opinions about this issue, if there isn't any by the end of the day, I will mark this answer as accepted